# Plotly Dash bar graph being segmented

Tags: pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a simple graph that displays the responses to a survey question. Normally, the bar graph will show as a solid bar with a total count of the amount represented by the bar, however when I do so, it shows the bar being segmented by the total count. The result is a bar graph that looks like blocks being stacked on top of each other and, when hovering over the bar, only gives a count of 1. Is there a way to change how it looks, or am I just approaching this the wrong way?

[image: Here is what my graph looks like]

And here is my code:

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

df = pd.read_csv('dp-export-296620.csv')

df0 = df.EntityType

fig = px.bar(df0, x='EntityType', color='EntityType')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id = "graph",
        figure = fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. There's probably something cleaner but here's what I did.

Instead of simply

```
df0 = df.EntityType
fig = px.bar(df0, x='EntityType', color='EntityType')
```

I did the following:

```
df0 = df['EntityType'].value_counts().rename_axis('EntityType').reset_index(name='counts')
fig = px.bar(df0, x="EntityType", y="counts", color = "EntityType")
```

I figure that the fix has to do with the reset_index line.